# How to get the absolute file path from the system PATH in C++?

Tags: c++, path, boost-filesystem

Is it possible to get the full path to the file by its name if it is in the system PATH?

For example, I have `cmake` in my PATH. Can I get the full path to it using C++ filesystem library? I just want to make cross-platform check for file existence.

Comment: Looks like boost has search_path: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost/process/search_path.html

Comment: @drescherjm, thank you! Just what I need. Can you make it as answer?

Comment: Maybe also checkout std::filesystem, if/when C++17 available: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Boost.Process** has this functionality in [search_path](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost/process/search_path.html) . Here is a small linux example testing search path to find the location of the `sh` executable in the system path.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/process/search_path.hpp>
#include <string>

int main()
{ 
    auto myPath = boost::process::search_path("sh");

    std::cout << "sh executable path " << myPath << std::endl;

}
```

Live Environment to test:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/c3TbKq4sliBjxRVc

Output:

> Start 
>   sh path "/bin/sh" 
>   0 
>   Finish